# DBUS-libdbus string size changes

Tags: dbus

I am using libdbus-1 for IPC.
I have observed that there is an unexpected behavior when I use DBUS_TYPE_STRING.

Sending side:
str.size() is 20

dbus_message_iter_append_basic (&argsIter, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &str);

Receiver side:

dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&argsIter, &str)

str.size() becomes 449

However content of the string I can print with [%s] specifier and it is same at sender and receiver.

If I increase the size of string at sender to be more than 449 the receiver side size becomes aroun 820~

Is it normal behaviour ?
I was expecting size to be same at sender and receiver.

thanks n regards
tanweer

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're passing the wrong type to `dbus_message_iter_get_basic`. That will crash the application eventually.

Docs have an [example](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/api/html/group__DBusMessage.html#ga41c23a05e552d0574d0444d4693d18ab) with something like that:

```
DBusBasicValue value;
dbus_message_iter_get_basic(&read_iter, &value);
```

Then, to get a `std::string` from it, use `value.str` which is of type `char*`.